# Magento 2.2.5 large multi-store catalog categories not updating

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, category, catalog, upgrade

I have a drop down Make Model Year parts finder on my store's front end that uses a three-level category tree with `3,000` subcategories. The same tree is used across five stores with `subcategories enabled or disabled` depending on the business need.

In `Magento 1.7` it was quick and easy to update any level of category. Just set indexing to Manual Update then reindex after updating.

The root parts finder category should be set

> Default > Disabled
>   Stores 1 - 5 > Enabled

When `migrating to 2.2.5,` some category settings were lost. All stores now have the root parts finder catalog Enabled setting with Use Default box checked. I can change the `Default Store setting from Enabled to Disabled` but cannot stop the `other stores from using the default setting`. When I uncheck Use Default in any store, then save, the Please Wait for wheel spins for `10 mins` before returning a `503 error`, and the update is not saved.

My hosting admin has already increased the Apache timeout significantly.

So what I need is a `MySQL` workaround to uncheck Use Default (Enable) in stores 1-5. I can then change the Default Store from Enabled to Disabled without affecting stores 1-5.

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting this, Magento announced 2.2.6. Upgraded and problem solved.